# Search bar seems to be acting as if its position is sticky but I have it set to fixed yet it still moves down when I scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

NOTE: TO VIEW SEARCH BAR BE SURE TO OPEN THE SNIPPET IN FULL SCREEN

Can someone help me fix this search button so that it doesnt move down the screen when I scroll.

I have it set to **position: fixed** but for some reason its still scrolling down.

Here is my website so far and I have the search bar on the far right corner. See snippet below (also please view it in full screen to see the search bar properly):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pathway+Gothic+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kaushan+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Teko:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alfa+Slab+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Acme&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@1,200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fjalla+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Permanent+Marker&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Allerta&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=yes" />
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            background: white;

        }

        .third-level-menu {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: -190px;
            width: 190px;
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            display: none;
        }

        .third-level-menu>li {
            height: 45px;
            background-color: #6640C1;
            background: #6640C1;
        }

        .third-level-menu>li:hover {
            background-color: gold;
        }

        .second-level-menu {
            position: absolute;
            top: 45px;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            /* width: 273.2px; */
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            display: none;
        }

        .second-level-menu>li {
            position: relative;
            height: 45px;
            background-color: #6640C1;
            background: #6640C1;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .second-level-menu>li:hover {
            background-color: gold;
        }

        .top-level-menu {
            display: flex;
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            z-index: 1;
            justify-content: space-between;

        }

        .top-level-menu>li {
            position: relative;
            height: 30px;
            /* width: 273.2px; */
            background: #6640C1;
            z-index: 2;
            text-align: center;
            flex: 1;

        }

        .top-level-menu>li:hover {
            background-color: gold !important;
        }

        .top-level-menu li:hover>ul {
            /* On hover, display the next level's menu */
            display: inline;


        }


        /* Menu Link Styles */

        .top-level-menu a

        /* Apply to all links inside the multi-level menu */
            {
            font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 0 0 0 10px;
            background: #6640C1;


            /* Make the link cover the entire list item-container */
            display: block;
            line-height: 45px;
        }

        .top-level-menu a:hover {
            color: #000000;
            background-color: gold;
        }


        .container1 {
            max-width: 1200px;
            margin: auto;
            background-color: white;
            overflow: auto;

        }


        .gallery {
            margin: 5px;
            border: 5px solid black;
            border-radius: 5%;
            float: left;
            width: 390px;


        }

        .gallery img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            border-radius: 5%;

        }

        .gallery:hover {
            transform: scale(1.03);
        }

        .desc {
            padding: 15px;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
            ;
        }


        #main-title {
            font-family: 'Alfa Slab One', cursive;
            color: black;
            font-size: 60px;
            margin: 20px;
            padding: 30px;
            position: relative;
            bottom: -20px;
            background-color: transparent;
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
        }


        .footer {
            background-color: black;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
            width: 100%;
            color: white;
            height: 300px;
        }

        .footer a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
        }

        .container2 {
            max-width: 1500px;
            margin: auto;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        .container-top {
            position: fixed;
            background-color: gold;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 10%;
            z-index: 1;
            text-align: center;

        }

        .top {
            display: inline-block;
            font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
            font-size: 30px;
            width: 100%;
            margin: -20px;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        body {
            font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
        }

        .mySlides {
            object-fit: cover;
            width: 100%;


        }

        .moving-images {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        /* Slideshow container */
        .slideshow-container {
            max-width: auto;
            position: relative;
            margin-top: -4%;



        }

        /* Caption text */
        .text {
            color: #f2f2f2;
            font-size: 15px;
            padding: 8px 12px;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 8px;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }


        /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
        .dot {
            height: 15px;
            width: 15px;
            margin: 2px 2px;
            background-color: #bbb;
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: inline-block;
            transition: background-color 0.6s ease;

        }

        .active {
            background-color: #717171;
        }

        /* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
        @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
            .text {
                font-size: 11px
            }
        }

        .arrow {
            border: solid white;
            border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 3px;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .arrow i:hover {
            color: black;
        }

        .down {
            transform: rotate(45deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        }

        .title-block {
            position: relative;
            background-color: white;
            font-family: 'Alfa Slab One', cursive;
            width: 100%;
            color: black;
            margin: 50px 0 0 0px;
            height: 20px;
            text-decoration: none;

        }

        :root {
            --line-thickness: 0.1em;
            --glass-size: 50%;
            --icon-height: 2.5rem;
            --transition-speed: 0.15s;
            --timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.66, 1.51, 0.77, 1.13);
            --icon-color: black;
        }

        /* this is already done  */

        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;


        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            background: white;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;

        }

        .search-icon {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            max-width: 20em;
            transition: all var(--transition-speed) linear, border-color 0s linear var(--transition-speed);
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 400px;
            left: 0;
            margin: auto;
            border: solid var(--line-thickness);
            border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
            border-radius: 100px;
            padding: 0.25em;
        }

        .search-icon__wrapper {
            width: var(--icon-height);
            height: var(--icon-height);
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 100px;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin: auto 0;
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
            transition: all 0 linear;
        }

        .search-icon__wrapper:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .search-icon__input {
            background: none;
            text-align: center;
            outline: none;
            display: block;
            border: none;
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
            width: calc(90% - (var(--icon-height) / 2 + 1rem));
            margin-right: 6rem;
            height: 100%;
            border-radius: 100px;
            transition: all var(--transition-speed) linear;
            font-size: 20px;
            padding: 0 0.5em;
            color: black;


        }

        .search-icon__input::placeholder {
            color: grey;
        }

        .search-icon__glass {
            width: var(--glass-size);
            height: var(--glass-size);
            border: solid var(--line-thickness);
            border-color: var(--icon-color);
            border-radius: 100px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
            transition: all var(--transition-speed) var(--timing-function) var(--transition-speed), border-color 0s linear var(--transition-speed);
        }

        .search-icon__handle {
            height: calc(100% - var(--glass-size));
            width: var(--line-thickness);
            margin: 0 auto;
            background: var(--icon-color);
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 0 0 100px 100px;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            transition: all var(--transition-speed) var(--timing-function);
            transition-delay: var(--transition-speed);
        }

        .search-icon__handle::after {
            content: "";
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border-radius: inherit;
            background: var(--icon-color);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
            transition: all var(--transition-speed) var(--timing-function);
            transition-delay: 0s;

        }

        .search-icon.open {
            width: 200px;
            border-color: var(--icon-color);
            transition-delay: var(--transition-speed);
        }

        .search-icon.open .search-icon__input {
            transition-delay: var(--transition-speed);
        }

        .search-icon.open .search-icon__glass {
            width: 45%;
            height: 45%;
            transition: all var(--transition-speed) var(--timing-function) 0s, border-color 0s linear var(--transition-speed);
            border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        .search-icon.open .search-icon__handle {
            bottom: calc(50% - (100% - var(--glass-size)) / 2);
            border-radius: 100px;
            transition-delay: 0s;
        }

        .search-icon.open .search-icon__handle::after {
            transition-delay: var(--transition-speed);
            transform: rotate(90deg);
        }
    </style>
    <title>TheLeague.com</title>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <div class="container-top">
            <div class="top">
                <p>Shop 20% Off All Jerseys Now!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="title-block">
            <div style="float:right; margin: 0 auto;">
                <div class=" search-icon" style="margin-right: 50px; position: fixed;">
                    <input class="search-icon__input" placeholder="search ...">

                    <div class="search-icon__wrapper">
                        <div class="search-icon__glass"></div>
                        <div class="search-icon__handle"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div style="margin:0 auto; width:300px; padding: 1px 0 50px 0; font-size: 25px;">
            <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#">
                <h1 style="color: black;">The<u>League</u></h1>
            </a>

        </div>

        </div>

        <!-- <div>
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="#">
                    <h1 id="main-title">The<u>League</u></h1>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div> -->
        <ul class="top-level-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" style="font-size: 20px;"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tag" style="font-size: 20px"></i> Shop All &#x25BC; </a>
                <ul class="second-level-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Jerseys</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hats</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gym Shorts</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-flask" style="font-size: 20px;"></i> Customize</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-futbol-o" style="font-size: 20px;"></i> Teams &#x25BC;</a>
                <ul class="second-level-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Soccer</a>
                        <ul class="third-level-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Barcelona</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">PSG</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Real Madrid</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Basketball</a>
                        <ul class="third-level-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Golden State Warriors</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Celtics</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Chicago Bulls</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Football</a>
                        <ul class="third-level-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">New England Patriots</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Ravens</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Atlanta Falcons</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 20px;"></i> Contacts Us</a>
            </li>
            </li>

        </ul>

        <div class="slideshow-container moving-images">

            <div class="mySlides">
                <img src="https://images.daznservices.com/di/library/sporting_news/a/fe/kobe-bryant-041315-getty-ftrjpg_hnmwtxmeqtvu1fyv5fnzn6abh.jpg?t=926331162&quality=100"
                    alt="kobe holding shirt" style="width:100%">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides">
                <img src="https://images.hdqwalls.com/download/lionel-messi-fc-art-1m-1366x768.jpg" style="width:100%">
                <!-- <div class="text">Caption Two</div> -->
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides">
                <img src="https://images.wallpapersden.com/image/download/tom-brady-new-england-patriots-football_21828_1366x768.jpg"
                    style="width:100%;">
                <!-- <div class="text">Caption Three</div> -->
            </div>
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)"><strong>&#10094; Prev</strong>
                </button>
                <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)"><strong>Next &#10095;</strong>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:center; margin: 10px;">
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
        </div>


        <!-- JavaScript -->

        <script>
            var slideIndex = 1;
            showDivs(slideIndex);

            function plusDivs(n) {
                showDivs(slideIndex += n);
            }

            function showDivs(n) {
                var i;
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
                if (n > x.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
                if (n < 1) { slideIndex = x.length }
                for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    x[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
            }




            var slideIndex = 0;
            showSlides();

            function showSlides() {
                var i;
                var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
                var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
                for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                    slides[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                slideIndex++;
                if (slideIndex > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
                for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
                }
                slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
                dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
                setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 2 seconds
            }
            const searchIcon = document.querySelector(".search-icon__wrapper");

            searchIcon.addEventListener("click", e => searchIcon.parentElement.classList.toggle("open"))
        </script>

        <!-- End of JavaScript -->

        <div style="margin: 30px;">
            <hr>
            </hr>
        </div>

        <br><br>
        <h3 style="text-align: center;font-size: 30px; color: black;font-family:'Fjalla One', sans-serif; ;">Featured
            Jerseys</h3><br><br><br>
        <div class="container1">
            <div class="gallery">
                <img src="https://www.teamzo.com/images/re-2019-2020-barcelona-home-nike-shirt-kids-messi-10-1559836177.png"
                    alt="The image shows the 2019-2020 Barcelona jersey">
                <div class="desc"> Barcelona 2019: Messi Jersey </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery">
                <img src="https://fanatics.frgimages.com/FFImage/thumb.aspx?i=/productimages/_1768000/altimages/FF_1768829ALT1_full.jpg&w=900"
                    alt="The image shows the 2019-2020 Barcelona jersey">
                <div class="desc"> Golden State Warriors 2019: StephCurry Jersey </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery">
                <img src="https://images.footballfanatics.com/FFImage/thumb.aspx?i=/productimages/_3775000/altimages/ff_3775300-29e956db2213fbdbcf67alt1_full.jpg&w=325"
                    alt="The image shows the 2019-2020 Barcelona jersey">
                <div class="desc"> Canucks 2019: Customizable Jersey </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery">
                <img src="https://contestimg.wish.com/api/webimage/5e86c1d100c605394a614f9c-large.jpg?cache_buster=71f3e987b756bb4df19be721d299a68b"
                    alt="The image shows the 2019-2020 Barcelona jersey">
                <div class="desc"> Patriots 2019: Tom Brady Jersey </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery">
                <img src="https://fanatics.frgimages.com/FFImage/thumb.aspx?i=/productimages/_3609000/altimages/ff_3609123-ef2947d2ef78011fbfc1alt3_full.jpg&w=600"
                    alt="The image shows the 2019-2020 Barcelona jersey">
                <div class="desc"> PSG 2019: Neymar Jersey </div>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0271/0975/2920/products/thumb.jpg?v=1580412625"
                    alt="The image shows the 2019-2020 Barcelona jersey">
                <div class="desc"> Lakers 2019: Kobe Bryant Jersey </div>
            </div>

        </div>


        <div style="margin: 30px;">
            <hr>
            </hr>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <div style="float: left; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0 0 0 40px;">
                <p><a href="#"><strong>Find a Store</strong></a></p>
                <p><a href="#"><strong>Sign Up For Email</strong></a></p>
                <p><a href="#"><strong>Become A Member</strong></a></p>
                <p><a href="#"><strong>Site Feedback</strong></a></p>
            </div>
            <div style="float:right; margin: 0 auto; width: 300px;">
                <p>Get Help</p>
                <p>Order Status</p>
                <p>Shipping and Delivery</p>
                <p>Returns</p>
                <p>Payment Options</p>
                <p>Contact Us</p>
            </div>
            <div style="margin:0 auto; width:200px; padding:4px 0 0 0;">
                <strong>
                    <p>About The League</p>
                </strong>
                <p>News</p>
                <p>Careers</p>
                <p>Investors</p>
                <p>Sustainability</p>
            </div>
            <div style="margin: 30px; color: white;"><br>
                <hr>
                </hr>
            </div>

        </div>




    </main>
</body>





</html>
```

Comment: position fixed will always be fixed at a defined position. if you scroll, the element scrolls with you. What you're looking for is position: absolute

Comment: As far as I can see it always remains at the same position. Not scrolling down as as what you'd expected from `pos:fixed`

Comment: I changed it to position: absolute, and it just disappears for some reason. Not sure what to change to keep it fixed to the top right corner

Comment: If you keep the search with your header, "20% off...", you'll see the effect that you expect

Comment: what do you mean by "keep the search with your header"? Do you mean in the same div as my "header" element?

Comment: For some reason Position: relative, did the trick. I have no idea, but im just gunna take the win. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the positioning of your **container-top**.

The position:*Fixed* effects the element in such a way that it follows the user's viewport. the position *Absolute*, on the other hand, takes the actual document into consideration.

Have a look at w3schools description here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: The container-top class is for that "20% off..." element at the top of the screen. What I was referring too is the expandable search bar on thr right of the screen. If you expand the snippet and view it in full screen youll see the search bar move up and down when you scroll which isnt what I was hoping it would do

Answer (score 0):

You should define the position to absolute.  Fixed means that it is always fixed to the same position on the screen, while absolute will force it to stay where it is in the element.

Comment: I changed it to absolute but for some reason that makes the whole search icon disappear